# Buttons at bottom not fully visible [TableLayout]

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to add buttons using TableRow but two buttons in last row are cut at bottom or are not fully visible. What should b e done in order to get those buttons fully visible?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="in.ashirvad.dhruv.krust.Technical">
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:text="Button 1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
            </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Button 2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Button 3" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Button 4" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Button 5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:text="Button 6" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

[image]

P.S.- I tried on a device which doesn't have a navigation bar but it did not work.

Comment: post the layout that contains the toolbar and tabs please

Answer (score 0):

Remove ScrollView and all your 6 buttons will be on the screen

Comment: I want the page to be scrollable